# Programming SPC56XX PowerPC MCUs

Tags: programming, jtag

I found that [SPC56](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/sense_power/FM2098/SC963?icmp=sc963_pron_launch-eiger_apr2015&sc=spc5-pr1) is perfect solution for my hobby automotive project. There are several C compilers.
I used to work with Cortex-M3/4 cores and it always was easy to find good program/debug solution for a small amount of money.
I want to give a try this MCU, I got one but cannot find any cheap solution for program (even without debug) just to make sure I can handle it at all.
Official hardware starts from 150$
May be J-link can be used in this case? As memory mapping is not a secret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Available tools is a important criterion for choosing a microcontroller.  Apparently you chose poorly.  Go back and do it again.

There are many many microcontrollers out there, and I doubt this one does anything particularly unique that others can't do.  All the Microchip PIC line, for example, is supported by free software tools, and the only hardware a hobbyist needs is the low cost PicKit3 programmer/debugger.

Comment: The most important thing I need is automotive temp. range, and 5V ADC (I cannot use external ADCs or use level-shifting). I wasn't able to find any MCU with it. Microchip PIC is lacking performance and PIC32 is too expensive.

Comment: @pugnator You cannot even use a simple voltage divider to scale down the voltage for the ADC?

Comment: @pug: There are plenty of automotive-temp parts out there.  In the Microchip line, look for the "E" temperature range.  "Too expensive" makes no sense, especially for a one-off project like this where the cost of the tools dominates anyway.  What's cheaper, a $2 micro with $150 tools, or a $3 micro with $30 tools.  You do the math.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop I agree, I was wrong from this point of view. Thank you a lot

Comment: @Bence Kaulics noisy lines and huge temperature instability. And the voltage can float 4.0-4.1V and I must not lost such a drop. Seems like external precision ADC is the only correct way